# How to configure Java SecurityManager to allow to read all properties from given file

Tags: java, security, tomcat, securitymanager

I'm currently trying to create a policy file for the Nexus repository manager running on Tomcat.

Nexus tries to read the file `WEB-INF/plexus.properties` (for which I already granted permission), and seems to try to read all properties from there, which fails because it is missing the following permission:

```
java.security.PropertyPermission * read,write
```

How do I configure the SecurityManager to allow reading all properties from this specific file? If I add this to the policy-file:

```
permission java.security.PropertyPermision "*", "read,write"
```

I'll grant the permission to read and alter all Properties, even System properties, won't I?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no `java.security.PropertyPermission`, you probably meant `java.util.PropertyPermission`
2. As far as I understand the `java.util.PropertyPermission` has nothing to do with reading properties from user-defined `.property`-files. It is only checked for system properties (i.e. `System.getProperty()` and `System.setProperty()`.

Which errors do you get that make you think you need anything but the read-file permission?

Comment: There is no class but the String "java.security.PropertyPermission" is used in the SecurityManager.

Comment: @Aaron: that's what I thought first, but I don't find any documentation mentioning "java.security.PropertyPermission". Can you point me at such documentation? Preferably by Sun itself.

Answer (score 0):

java.security.PropertyPermission should be a valid class name.
Its qualified name is used as a perm_class_name in policy file as defined in jaas spec :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html#FileSyntax

```
grant <signer(s) field>, <codeBase URL> 
  <Principal field(s)> {
    permission perm_class_name "target_name", "action";
    ....
    permission perm_class_name "target_name", "action";
  };
```

Joachim Sauer is right -> It is only checked for system properties.

I think you should use `java.io.FilePermission` as perm_class_name.
JavaDoc for this class will explain you its parameters (yes this is a java class !!)

BR

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "*", specify the name of the properties files.